Movie that will come out about a nanny terrorizing children with gun?
I saw this trailer about a young nanny taking care of some children but although she seems nice at the beginning she soon starts terrorizing the kids with some twisted games and even a gun. 
The setting was in a big house apparently away from neighbors because the nanny at some point takes the children to the backyard with no fear of being watched. The nanny I remember was a young woman like around 19 years old, long straight black hair. She had a revolver.
I think there were two kids, a girl and a boy, around 8 years old, I remember a scene where the boy was in the backyard unconscious. The girl was told to keep silence about their "game" by the nanny at some point in the trailer.
I remember watching the video on a website but can't find it ,I got there from an external page.
I don't remember the name of it or if it's gonna be a movie coming out this year (though it seemed like it will). 

Did you see it in a theater or on TV or as a streaming ad? I looked through all the horror, thriller, and drama trailers I could find and I didn't find anything matching your description. Closest things I found was The Boy (Nanny for a boy who is an evil doll) and Dementia (Home care giver for elderly man who is evil (the nanny, not the old man, well he might be too)).

I don't know it came put recently or this year, it seemed like a recent movie, I saw the video o a website but don't know which

Sounds like you're after the creepy Emelie. From an online review:

[W]hen the Thompsons head out to spend the evening of their anniversary at a fancy restaurant, they have no idea what they’re letting their kids in for. Owing to their usual babysitter being unavailable, the Thompsons enlist the help of her well-reputed friend, Anna. Already known to the audience, however, is that Anna has been the victim of a violent kidnapping – and the girl who turns up at the door (played by Sarah Bolger) is someone different entirely… the titular Emelie, masquerading as the experienced childminder.

Emelie plays sick games with the kids and at some point a gun comes into play. It's been making the rounds at film festivals and will be released in the US proper in March 2016. Here's the trailer:



